# Making a palette permanently active/focused?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, palette, nspanel

Is there a simple way that I can make my application's floating tool palettes permanently active? They are all relevant to the open document, so there is no reason for them to be inactive at any point in time.

Comment: What do you mean by "permanently active"?  It can't be key all the time or you wouldn't be able to do anything in other windows.

Comment: If it can't actually be key, it needs to at least be drawn as if it were.

Comment: Well, it can be key, but it won't be all the time if you click on another window.

Comment: What I'm really looking for, then, is for the titlebar and controls to never be drawn as inactive.

Comment: I think you're trying to do something that (probably) can't be done. If you look at palettes in Apple's programs such as Numbers or Pages, the palettes only become key if you click in a text field or on the title bar, but you can still interact with any of the other controls without having to click on the window first to activate it -- in that sense it's always active even if not drawn that way. If the panel is floating and becomesKeyOnlyIfNeeded is set to YES, then you'll get a palette that looks like the Apple standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NSPanel` for the utility window.
That way the panel can also properly hide when the app is not active (it's a flag, though).

Consider making it 'Non-Activating':

> If the receiver is a non-activating panel, then it becomes key only if the hit view returns YES from needsPanelToBecomeKey. This way, a non-activating panel can control whether it takes keyboard focus.

Comment: I'm already using NSPanel (note the tag). It's also non-activating. Unfortunately, the palette's titlebar can still appear inactive.

Comment: Funny. Works fine for my apps (plenty of palettes..)